# XSocket works fine on localhost, but not on an intranet enviroment

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, xsockets.net

I have an asp.net mvc3 web app using XSocket, it works fine locally, but it doesn't on my intranet.

I've configured the xsockets windows service and runs fine.
I've copied my "plugins" (DLL's and dependencies) on the right directory and runs fine.

The problem is when I try to access to the application via intranet, the connection always says closed.

Do I need to point to a specific IP address/server name?

My javascript code that runs fine in localhost:

```
var url = "ws://127.0.0.1:4507/";
var controller = "Chat";
var mensajes = $('#messages');
var mensaje = $('#message');

var ws = new XSockets.WebSocket(url + controller);

function send() {
    if (mensaje.val() != '') {
        ws.trigger('sendall', { message: mensaje.val() });
        mensaje.attr('value', '');
    }
}

$(function () {
    ws.bind(XSockets.Events.open, function () {
        console.log("opened");
    });
    ws.bind(XSockets.Events.close, function () {
        console.log("closed");
    });
    ws.bind(XSockets.Events.onError, function (err) {
        console.log("error", err);
    });
    ws.bind('sendall', function (mensaje) {
        console.log(mensaje);
        mensajes.prepend($('<div>').text(mensaje));
    });

    mensaje.on('keyup', function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13 || e.keyCode == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            send();
        }
    });

    $('#publish').click(function () {
        send();
    });
});
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi,  Do you have a custom configuration?  I see that you are running on 127.0.0.1:4507 ,i suppose that is on your local machine that the example above is based on?


And yes, if the server is running on for instane; 192.168.0.100, you need the set that as the Uri in the configuration class, as well as you need to use ws://192.160.0.100/Chat in your JavaScript


http://xsockets.net/api/net-c/creating-custom-configuration-plugin

Comment: Thanks for answering. I will try again with the Custom configuration...

Comment: Do you know where I need to implement the CustomConfigurationLoader? I have this:

[Export(typeof(CustomConfigurationLoader))]
    public class ChatController : XSocketController
    {
        public XReply SendAll(string message)
        {
            return new XReply(message).ToAll();
        }
    }
and now my javascript looks like:
var ws = new XSockets.WebSocket("ws://192.168.1.102:4507/Chat", "Chat", null);

But I get this error message:

error

Object { CustomMessage=

"The handler name was not found in loaded plugins"

, Type=

"XSocketException"

, Message=

""

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you need to configure your server to have Uri that points to your computer adress* (not localhost, not 127.0.0.1!). Then this:

```
var url = "ws://127.0.0.1:4507/";
```

Needs to exactly match that address (it can be a domain name, but as for starters, better do it with ip).

This:

```
var ws = new XSockets.WebSocket(url + controller);
```

Needs to look like that:

```
var ws = new XSockets.WebSocket("ws://my.ip.add.res:myport/myController", myController, null); //null can contain an array of parameters that you want to send to a server, but if you are just starting, leave this with null
```

Also, when I was struggling with my configuration, many times I bite my pillow because I was trying with different ports and forgot about firewall. So don't forget about it. :)

I will be here for like 30-40 minutes more, then I am going to sleep, if you will have any problems and will respond within that timespan, I will stay here and try to help you, since I was going through this too, and it hurt as hell. :)

PS. You can also contact developers at `contact@xsockets.net`, they are really cool guys and will surely help you out!

*edit: by *computer address* I mean computer, that is hosting the xsockets server.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Obviously 127.0.0.1 is just for the test enviroment. The firewall is not a problem, I've already configured... I will try again with the Custom configuration...

Comment: Do you know where I need to implement the CustomConfigurationLoader? I have this:

[Export(typeof(CustomConfigurationLoader))]
    public class ChatController : XSocketController
    {
        public XReply SendAll(string message)
        {
            return new XReply(message).ToAll();
        }
    }
and now my javascript looks like:
var ws = new XSockets.WebSocket("ws://192.168.1.102:4507/Chat", "Chat", null);

But I get this error message:

error

Object { CustomMessage=

"The handler name was not found in loaded plugins"

, Type=

"XSocketException"

, Message=

""

}

Comment: @JoaquinAlberto: I assume you are using XSockets 2.5 (the newest one). You don't need anything like `[Export(typeof(CustomConfigurationLoader))]`  on your `ChatController`. Also, `ChatController` is a controller, and not a config file. If you want to use custom config, it needs to look like that: `http://bit.ly/11gBMiy` and you just put that in your `myProject.XSocketsNET.XSocketServerPlugins` namespace.

Comment: @JoaquinAlberto: Also, if you have more code to post, try `pastebin.com`, since it is really hard to look at code posted in this comments, so I am not sure if I understood everything correctly. :)

Comment: Looking at your error message ; The handler name was not found" , means that the Controller is not loaded into the server, did you drop it into the PluginFolder, if a windows service?  Drop it in the "root" ?